# How can I specify multiple address_space structs for an inode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, page-caching

Say that two different processes each open two different files. Normally, they would each have their own inode and each inode would have their own `struct address_space` (this is the guy who remembers where the page cache pages are in memory).

But, let's say I *knew* that these files were initially identical. I want to come up with a way to smart share caching to the extent possible.

I was considering these strategies:

1. Add a new field to the `struct address_space` struct: a pointer to a "parent". Then, whenever I look for an existing page, I'll also look in the parent (if it exists). Whenever I write to a page, I will therefore need to fault and C-O-W the page into the main address_space. Both files will share the common parent.
2. Group each related set of `struct address_space` in a linked list. Whenever I look for an existing page, search the entire linked list. In this scenario, though, it would be disallowed to "find" a dirty page on a friend's address_space. In other words, if a page gets dirty it can't be used as a backup anymore. In this scenario, if anyone ever wrote data to the file, I would need to disassociate the address_spaces. I would also need some sort of C-O-W behavior to sustain this as well.

Can anyone tell me:

- Is either or both of these ideas are sound?
- What things in particular should I watch out for?

As a point of reference, I am doing a custom kernel hack to save memory because on my system there are multiple identical files being opened (but not the same inode = not sharing pagecache).

**EDIT: 3rd idea:**

- Keep a linked list of the "related" pagecache `address_space` and then every time we read from disk, update every `address_space` struct that's open. Opening a new related file would have to cause a big page table copying thing to happen, except skip any dirty pages.

Comment: Your idea sounds interesting and reminds me of [KSM](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/ksm.txt). But KSM doesn't merge pagecache pages, maybe there was no need or there's another reason.

Comment: Yes, similar to KSM. Except unlike KSM, I want to use special knowledge of what's going on to catch and share pages as they happen, rather then comparing the data later and realizing they're the same.

Comment: @RobertMartin:  I haven't looked at that part of the kernel since Unix, but aren't those separate `struct file` pointing to the same `inode`?

Comment: If they're the same inode, things take care of themselves, yeah. But in my case, I have _different_ inodes but identical file contents. It's because I have a union filesystem and I'm opening the files 'rw'